# Azure kubernetes - Prometheus accessing the application secured with Azure AD

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-active-directory, prometheus, azure-aks

I am trying to implement Prometheus for my application hosted on Azure kubernetes. Currently the application does not have any authentication enabled, Prometheus is working fine.

However I would be enabling the Azure AD authentication to protect the application. In this case, would it break the Prometheus metric collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However I would be enabling the Azure AD authentication to protect the application. In this case, would it break the Prometheus metric collection?

This depends on how the application is implemented.

It is not common to add authentication also to the metrics endpoint. But sometimes the metrics endpoint is served on another port, e.g. [Management Server Port](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-customizing-management-server-port) for Spring Boot.